# GCP Default Project - change from console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to change my default project (deleted the previous one). Can't find documentation for how to do this from either the console or the cli. Seems to be a pretty common requirement but ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the GCP Console via the url `https://console.cloud.google.com/` will open the project selected during the last connection. (probably cached on your browser local storage).

For `gcloud` commands, you can change the default project with :

```
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
```

or initialize a new environment with:

```
gcloud init
```

Also note that you can [create multiple configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations)s and then switch between them easily :

```
gcloud config configurations create CONFIG_NAME
gcloud config configurations activate CONFIG_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks! Also figured out how to do this from the command line: `gcloud init` presents you with a choice to go with the default, update the default or create a new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing the GCP UI console, it may also be useful to access the project (and consider bookmarking) the following:
https://console.cloud.google.com/welcome?project= `<project-ID>`

While updating the `<project-ID>` with the relevant project id of the desired project (note: it's always a good practice to double-check that the relevant project is indeed selected).